# Extend div to bottom of page

Tags: html, height, extend

I know this is a question that is asked a lot, but I couldn't find any solution at all to what should be a simple thing.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>

    <!--CSS STYLING-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../cssReset.css" />
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #menu {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #center {
            height: 250px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        #main {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='menu'>
    </div>
    <div id='center'>
    </div>
    <div id='main'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Prety simple, but I just can't make the last div extend to the bottom of the page. If I use "auto" it will not display anything, as there's no content. If I use 100%, it will use my browser height and create unecessary scrollbars.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand. What height do you want use for it? Your problem are the scrollbars?

Comment: I want the last div to go all the way down, but not further! The way that it is now, is passing trough the bottom of the screen and generating scroll bars.
I would be ok with simple hiding the scrollbars if there was an option for that, but I would have to hide it, only if the content of the 'main' div doesn't pass te bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always take the easy way out and use JavaScript. Here's a simple example.

```
<style>
DIV { margin: 0; }
</style>
<script>
function fixMain() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var center = document.getElementById("center");
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    var height = document.body.offsetHeight - (menu.offsetHeight + center.offsetHeight);
    main.style.height = height + 'px';
}
window.addEventListener("load", fixMain, false);
window.addEventListener("resize", fixMain, false);
</script>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! I wish there was a CSS only solution, but this seems to be fine.
Only one problem however... if there is in fact content inside the 'main' div, and it end up passing the bottom of the screen, the function will still be executed and then when I roll the screen down, the div will not be going until the end.

Comment: I did it! I put an "if" on the JS code to only execute the function if the main.offsetHeight is smaller than the content inside it (there's another div inside it with all the content, so I used it).

I'll mark your answer as the correct one, LastCoder. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

may be the following markup code would be what you are looking for just add a **"overflow:hidden"** in your css style sheet will fix your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>

    <!--CSS STYLING-->
    <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}   
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;   
        }
        #menu {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #center {
            height: 250px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        #main {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='menu'>
    </div>
    <div id='center'>
    </div>
    <div id='main'>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This would remove the scrollbar even if there's a lot of content, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your markup, it shows the last div 'main' extend to the bottom of the page.... what is being displayed for you? And what styling info is there in the referred cssReset.css ( although this would be overridden by the style on the page html

Comment: The 'main' is extending to the bottom, but it's going beyond it (creating a scroll bar)... the 'main' height is equal to my total browser height. I want it to be 100% of my browser height minus 350px (which corresponds to the 'menu' and 'center' divs).

The cssreset basicaly rests the margins, if I remove it, I still get the same result.

Comment: I am not sure what problem you can face with javascript approach mentioned by 'LastCoder' but I think you can probably use min-height/ max-height attributes if needed. Also, if you are giving pixels for one part, I doubt there's a css only way to make your main content extend till bottom of screen without using some script to know the browser height. Min- height can be used in the scenario wherein you want the element below the main, which could be a footer to be present below ,and you want to keep it below irrespective of the 'main' content height

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is what you are looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>

    <!--CSS STYLING-->
    <style>
        *{margin:0;padding:0}
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #menu {
            height: 10%;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #center {
            height: 25%;
            background-color: green;
        }
        #main {
            height: 75%;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='menu'>
    </div>
    <div id='center'>
    </div>
    <div id='main'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't use percentage in all the divs... there will be content in these divs which will have fixed heights an so on. It will break my layout if the user opens it on a smaller or larger screen.