# Making a div extend to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a `<div>` that always extends to the bottom of the page. A simliar problem was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821721/extend-div-to-bottom-of-page
However, I want to *only* use the div itself. My approach was the following javascript code (which would be executed each time the window is resized):

```
var total_height = $( window ).height();
var container = $( "div#container:first" )[0];

var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

var remaining_height = total_height - rect.top;

container.style.height = "" + remaining_height + "px";
```

The problem is that the height does not take padding/margins into account so the div is a little bit too large. I would like to set the height such that the offsetHeight is equal to the `remaining_height`, but I am not sure how I can achieve the effect... Any ideas?

Comment: `#container:first` implies that you have multiple `ID` elements with the same ID name **which is wrong**

Comment: maybe `#container div:first` ?!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/ like in `.outerHeight(true)`?

Comment: Well, `outerHeight()` gets the outer height. I want to set it.

Comment: Also, forget the `:first`, that was just wrong

Comment: Have you considered using box-sizing: border-box? Then outerHeight and height are the same. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in plain HTML & CSS by mimicking the desired `#container` background... actually setting it to to the `BODY` element:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hexa/2/edit)**

Or with JS / jQuery:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/hexa/3/edit)

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var $cont = $('#container'); // or use #containerParent if you have paddings
var contTop = $cont[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
$cont.height(windowHeight - contTop);
```

if you don't want to have a wrapper and you want to apply **paddings** to `#container`
 than go for it:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sodu/1/edit)**

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var $cont = $('#container');
var contH = $cont.outerHeight(true) - $cont.height(); // paddings, borders...
var contT = $cont[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
$cont.height(windowHeight - contT - contH);
```

Comment: You are not understanding me... Add `padding:10px;` to your `#container` in the css and you will see the problem...

Comment: @hfhc2 wrap your #container into a parent element and apply my code to that element. That simple

Comment: @hfhc2 I've clearly shown you in the demo that the only elements having padding are the content containers `.centered`

Comment: @hfhc2 edited my answer with (hopefully) what you need

Comment: Well, I see what you mean. My problem is the following: I have a div acting holding a menubar on top and one holding the actual content. I have more content than I can show, so I have added "overflow-y:scroll;" to the content div. I want to make sure that the overall document has no scrollbar while the content div does. This still doesn't quite work. But the padding does not seem to be the problem... See here: http://jsbin.com/sodu/3/edit

Comment: For the record: Under chrome the scrollbar on the right hand side of the window remains and there are two scrollbars side by side which is *not* what I want...

Comment: @hfhc2 you need to remove margin from BODY element (that was added by the browser as default)

Comment: Ading `margin:0;` to the `<body>` fixed everything up nicely. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The offsetHeight is just the value you get when you add the height of an element to it's padding-top and padding-bottom properties as well as the border values.

So can't you just subtract the padding top and bottom values and the border bottom/ top values from the remaining_height value to get the height you're after?

Comment: Again, if you can get this to work http://jsbin.com/sodu/3/edit I am all ears. But it seems like it is not a problem regarding padding...

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you said you wanted to extend a `<div>` to the bottom of a page, yet your calculations involve the use of `$( window ).height();` which returns the height of the browser viewport ([source](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height1)).

While working with the viewport dimensions might work for some cases, it might fail for example if you reload the page when the viewport is not at the top of the document.

With that in consideration, here's the code I used:

```
$(function() {

    //get the height of the document
    var docHeight = $( document ).height();
    var extended = $( "#extended" );
    //offset.top gets the top position related to the document, using border-box.
    var top = extended.offset().top;
    //get the margin, if any.
    var marginBottom = parseInt(extended.css( "margin-bottom" ), 10);
    //set the height so that the bottom margin (or the element) is on the bottom.
    extended.outerHeight(docHeight - top - marginBottom);

});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/zofi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

This works if the element has padding, border and/or margin.